# Can anyone suggest an alternative to Copperplate Gothic for web use?

Tags: fonts, font-face, website-design, web-fonts

Designer sent comps for a site using copperplate, I was wondering if anyone could suggest a good alternative that exists either on google fonts or as a font squirrel kit (preferably the former).

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot? I would go out on a limb and say that there are better fonts to use (I don´t really like copperplate :) ) But I´ll look for an alternative anyway.

Comment: Can you use a webfont instead?

Comment: @e100 I wish ;) google fonts are great, the issue can be rendering on some browsers.

Comment: What browsers, exactly? Webfonts ate supported back to IE7. Mobiles can handle webfonts unless they're using Opera Mini, which butchers everything so who cares. Unless you need to-the-pixel size metrics for JavaScript-based dimension calculation at loadtime (which is a REALLY esoteric requirement) you'll be fine with a webfont.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question,  the font we decided to use is

Alegreya SC

http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Alegreya+SC

We use it as a backup if the user doesn't have any of the main copperplate families on their machine.

thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: that's really nothing like Copperplate, though. Granted, Copperplate isn't always the best option to begin with--especially if we're talking body copy.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative. Not perfect, but close to Copperplate.

Balthazar: 
http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Balthazar

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about using the actual font, I would just create an @font-face kit yourself using Copperplate Gothic.

The only problem with @font-face, which is a major one, is that it can have a severe impact on site performance.

Comment: This used to be THE solution solution, but lately, I have found issues with the kit files for certain browsers and font squirrel, which has the best kit generator, is straight-up blocking some kits form being generated. +1 for the suggestion, though since it is a good one and this is not a web dev exchange per se. The best bet for kits is getting a  pre-compiled one from font squirrel.

Comment: You can't just create a font-face kit without properly licensing the font for web use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best I could find on google webfonts: [Syncopate](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Syncopate), [Cantarell](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Cantarell);
I suggest using both in bold. They are close except for the serifs of course, which I don´t find very attractive to be honest.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think either of these are anything like Copperplate Gothic.

Comment: Oh now that I see the links you´re right. I typed in COPPERFIELD in the selection part of google webfonts. Try it and you´ll see that they have their characteristics.

Comment: Of course only in Uppercase and bold ;)

Comment: @Jannik, Thanks will take a look. Cantarell seems like a decent alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The alternatives presented in other answers don't resemble Copperplate very closely, mainly in geometry. A hybrid approach would be to include Copperplate at the top of your font stack and use fallbacks. According to cssfontstack.com, Copperplate is installed on the majority of Windows and Macintosh computers. http://www.cssfontstack.com/Copperplate

I came here looking for ideas and this is the approach I'm going to take with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Libre Baskerville and increased the font spacing to 1px and I feel it is fairly close.

https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Libre+Baskerville